# Spring MVC session lost after external redirect in mobile app

Tags: spring-mvc, session, redirect, mobile-application

I have a Spring MVC app (browser site and mobile app). I'm redirecting to 3rd party payment site and then back to my app, where I have some things stored in session (using Spring Security). I do some validations etc and when everything is fine I redirect to my site.

So when doing it all in browser, it works. The payment site is opened in the same tab. After payment the payment site redirects back to my app, my session is there and everything is fine.

But when doing it in mobile app. Customer is redirected to payment site with opening it in external browser (so no iFrame). When the payment site redirects back to my app - the session is gone. All I have is Spring default anonymousUser when trying to get the session with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

Is there any chance to retrieve the session in mobile app case as well?